# Restore a Database from a .Bak file in Ubuntu CLI MySQL?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, mysql

I am currently trying to restore a database that is currently saved as a .bak file on a flash drive. I have MySQL installed on a headless install of Ubuntu so CLI is the only way I can restore this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.bak` doesn't define what format the database was dumped in. If it was dumped via `mysqldump` or compatible, then you need to run something like this `mysql databasename < /path/to/somefile.bak`. Note that if you don't have `.my.cnf` in your user's home directory with credentials, you will have to supply them with the above command as well.